# master: ssh: connect to host master port 22: Connection refused

Tags: linux, ubuntu, hadoop, hdfs

i am trying to start my hadoop cluster using the command "start-dfs.sh" but am getting errors as shown below

Starting namenodes on [master]

```
master: ssh: connect to host master port 22: Connection refused
```

Starting datanodes

```
master: ssh: connect to host master port 22: Connection refused
```

ive checked the ssh status, it then returns me:

```
 ssh.service - OpenBSD Secure Shell server
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/ssh.service; enabled; vendor preset: enab
   Active: failed (Result: start-limit-hit) since Tue 2020-02-04 14:15:01 +04; 2
  Process: 5017 ExecStartPre=/usr/sbin/sshd -t (code=exited, status=255)

Feb 04 14:15:00 hadoop-HP-Pro3500-Series systemd[1]: ssh.service: Unit entered f
Feb 04 14:15:00 hadoop-HP-Pro3500-Series systemd[1]: ssh.service: Failed with re
Feb 04 14:15:01 hadoop-HP-Pro3500-Series systemd[1]: ssh.service: Service hold-o
Feb 04 14:15:01 hadoop-HP-Pro3500-Series systemd[1]: Stopped OpenBSD Secure Shel
Feb 04 14:15:01 hadoop-HP-Pro3500-Series systemd[1]: ssh.service: Start request 
Feb 04 14:15:01 hadoop-HP-Pro3500-Series systemd[1]: Failed to start OpenBSD Sec
Feb 04 14:15:01 hadoop-HP-Pro3500-Series systemd[1]: ssh.service: Unit entered f
```

how to fix this?

Comment: You've cropped your logs so it's impossible to see why it failed and as such suggest how to fix it. Edit the question to include all the log lines.