# ssh: connect to host localhost port 22: Connection refused

Tags: linux, ubuntu, hadoop, hdfs

I have installed `hadoop` and `ssh`. `hadoop` was working fine, then today I am getting the error below when I run the command `sbin/start-dfs.sh`:

```
Starting namenodes on [localhost]
localhost: ssh: connect to host localhost port 22: Connection refused
Starting datanodes
localhost: ssh: connect to host localhost port 22: Connection refused
Starting secondary namenodes [chbpc-VirtualBox]
chbpc-VirtualBox: ssh: connect to host chbpc-virtualbox port 22: Connection refused
```

I've checked the ssh status, and I have the following error:

```
ssh.service - OpenBSD Secure Shell server
Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/ssh.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
Active: failed (Result: start-limit-hit) since Tue 2020-02-04 15:34:10 +04; 3h 35min ago
Process: 946 ExecStartPre=/usr/sbin/sshd -t (code=exited, status=255)

Feb 04 15:34:09 chbpc-VirtualBox systemd[1]: ssh.service: Control process exited, code=exited status=255
Feb 04 15:34:09 chbpc-VirtualBox systemd[1]: Failed to start OpenBSD Secure Shell server.
Feb 04 15:34:09 chbpc-VirtualBox systemd[1]: ssh.service: Unit entered failed state.
Feb 04 15:34:09 chbpc-VirtualBox systemd[1]: ssh.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Feb 04 15:34:10 chbpc-VirtualBox systemd[1]: ssh.service: Service hold-off time over, scheduling restart.
Feb 04 15:34:10 chbpc-VirtualBox systemd[1]: Stopped OpenBSD Secure Shell server.
Feb 04 15:34:10 chbpc-VirtualBox systemd[1]: ssh.service: Start request repeated too quickly.
Feb 04 15:34:10 chbpc-VirtualBox systemd[1]: Failed to start OpenBSD Secure Shell server.
Feb 04 15:34:10 chbpc-VirtualBox systemd[1]: ssh.service: Unit entered failed state.
Feb 04 15:34:10 chbpc-VirtualBox systemd[1]: ssh.service: Failed with result 'start-limit-hit'.
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: `systemctl status` only shows (the last) 10 lines of journal entries. Your logs may contain useful information, please check the output of `journalctl -b 0 -u ssh.service` or, equivalently, `systemctl --full --lines 1000 status ssh.service`, where 1000 can be any positive number. Then, please [edit](https://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/565738/edit) your question accordingly.

Comment: Also, is [this other question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/565707/315749) of yours related to this one? Do both of them refer to the same issue?

Comment: both questions refer to the same issue.